# Getting a answer from a driver in HEX

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, serial-port, ascii

i´m working in a communication between a software that i developed and a weighing module. I´m facing the following problem problem:
I´m receiving the data from a serial port in CHAR, but it goes untill 127, after this i start to receive a "?" and it converts to a "63".
There is a way of receiving the message back in HEX or do you have another solution maybe? Because i need the rest of the numbers from 127 to 255.

```
        SerialPort1.Write(message1)

        message = SerialPort1.ReadLine()

        peso1 = message.Chars(2)

        value1 = Convert.ToInt32(peso1)

        If pes2 = "?" Then
            value2 = 0
            If peso1 = "?" Then
                value1 = 0
            End If
        End If


        pes2 = message.Chars(1)
        value2 = Convert.ToInt32(pes2)

        pes3 = message.Chars(0)
        value3 = Convert.ToInt32(pes3)


        valuef = value1 + value2*255
        TextBox1.Text = valuef
        '
        tv1.Text = value1
        tv2.Text = value2
        tv3.Text = value3
```

Comment: surely you want to read bytes?

Comment: [SerialPort.Read Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.read(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What as the parameters to use serial.port.read() in bytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the device is sending ASCII characters then the encoding of the serial port will have to be something that has 256 values defined.  I believe this is one.

```
 System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)
```

Without knowing the protocol of the device it is hard to give a better answer.